# HTML/CSS : How to I make the item.image as an optional field?

Tags: html, css

I am making an e-marketplace project. I have kept the ImageField as optional in my database. However, I am unable to make it optional in the HTML page in the code below:

```
 <div class="mt-6 px-6 py-12 bg-gray-100 rounded-xl">
        <h2 class="mb-12 text-2xl text-center"> Newest items </h2>
        <div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-3">
            {%for item in items%}
                <div>
                <a href="#">
                <div>
                { % if (item.image.url) % }
                    <img src='{{ item.image.url}}' class="rounded-t-xl">
                { % endif % }
                </div>
            <div class="p-6 bg-white rounded-b-xl">
                <h2 class="text-2xl">{{item.name}}</h2>
                <p class="text-gray-500">Price: {{item.price}}</p>
                </div>
            </a>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
 </div>
```

How do I correctly write the if statement correctly to fetch item.image.url only when an image is available?

I tried to include an if statement as shown in code above.

Update: I could resolve it. Editing this post if someone else comes across this problem.
Solution was using if ...is not None.

Comment: Please always specify the language or framework you are using, if it's not plain HTML/CSS/JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% if item.image.url is not None %}
    <img src='{{ item.image.url}}' class="rounded-t-xl">
{% endif %}
```